# git stash после merge?

Tags: git

Если делается git merge into.
А там возникли конфликты, то можно ли затем использовать git stash, чтобы откатиться на состояние до merge, то есть на последний commit в этой ветке?

Или это надо делать по другому?

Comment: для отката неудачного (но ещё не завершенного мерджа) нужно использовать `git merge --abort`. Использование других команд во время мерджа (или ребейза) чревато полным развалом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git stash` засунет все текущие изменения в stash. В данном случае он не поможет.

После конфликтного `git merge` в папке проекта появились новые изменения в конфликтующих фаилах, которые будут использованы вашим difftool (или вами самими) для того что бы починить merge. Если сейчас сделать `git stash`, эти изменения попадут в stash, что избавит вас от проблемы, но в stash им находится абсолютно незачем если вы не собираетесь потом к ним вернутся.

Вместо этого, вам вероятно нужно от этих изменений избавится. Для этого можно использовать `git reset --hard`, `git merge --abort` или `git reset --merge`. Все 3 команды в вашем случае сделают одно и то же - удалят все изменения вызванные конфликтным (незаконченным) `git merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Git stash засовывает изменения в стеш.

Откатить коммит **git reset --soft HEAD~1**

Если он уже запушен - так же сделать **git push -f origin HEAD**

Comment: Ну вот он засовывает изменения merge в стеш?

Comment: push force? серьезно? что бы пофиксить конфлик мерджа?

Comment: А есть другой способ откатить изменения на сервере, без push?

Comment: git merge --abort - откатывает мерж

Comment: @DorinBotan а merge conflict - он локальный. Не нужно откатывать его на сервере